# Querying system data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I am trying find a column name in MySQL.

I use something like this in SQL Server:

```
SELECT
  sysobjects.name AS table_name, 
  syscolumns.name AS column_name, 
  systypes.name AS datatype, 
  syscolumns.LENGTH AS LENGTH
FROM sysobjects 
INNER JOIN
  syscolumns ON sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id 
INNER JOIN
  systypes ON syscolumns.xtype = systypes.xtype
WHERE (sysobjects.xtype = 'U')
AND (UPPER(syscolumns.name) like upper('%code%'))
ORDER BY sysobjects.name, syscolumns.colid
```

It returns a list of tables with their columns and for each column, the data type and length. In SQL Server, this information is stored in the `sysobjects`, `syscolumns` and `systypes` tables. Where can I find similar information in MySQL?

Comment: Is this an answer? xD

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this query? That might help someone answer whether it can be done in mysql (especially, if they are not familiar with SQL Server).

Comment: @AdamPorad, the query it looking for tables that contain a column name LIKE `%some_value%`.

Comment: @fthiella sorry, i don't speak english :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can query Information Schema for simalar information in MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Note only works with MySQL 5.0 or higher, Here is full documentation on Inforamtion Schema in MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-schema.html)

Comment: As an important note, these also work in SQL Server, so the original query can be rewritten using these standard views.

Comment: I am trying to search a column name.

Comment: than just add that column to the where clause when selecting from `columns` table. [here are documentation on column table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/columns-table.html)